# On macOS, Tornado's read_bytes hangs when it receives more than 1024 bytes at a time

Tags: python, macos, tornado

The source code is a simple echo server that receives 1024 bytes and returns them as is. Oddly enough, on macOS it hangs on inputs that are more than 1024 bytes. (raw socket / Twisted doesn't have this problem)

How to reproduce:

1. Run server. `python3 server.py`
2. Open other terminal, and run `nc localhost 1234` (The same is true for telnet)
3. Paste some arbitrary 1024 bytes and press Control+D (EOF)
4. Hang.

If I paste 1023 bytes, press Ctrl + D, then type 1 byte again and type Ctrl + D, echo is processed normally.

It works fine on Linux (on Docker).

```py
import tornado
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.tcpserver
import tornado.iostream

class EchoServer(tornado.tcpserver.TCPServer):
    async def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
        while True:
            try:
                message = await stream.read_bytes(1024)
                await stream.write(message)

            except tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError:
                break

server = EchoServer()
server.listen(1234)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

- OS: macOS 10.14.6
- Python version: 3.7.4
- Tornado version: 6.0.3 / 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I noticed that the nc used by macOS and the nc used by Linux are different. Opening Tornado server on macOS and nc on Linux (Docker) confirmed that it worked.